# How to refresh all select fields on changing to landscape mode with selectBoxIt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help. Was working on it but i couldn't solve the issue!

The documentation says it's possible to rebuild all sleect fields.
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#MethodAPI

I need a solution to rebuild all select fields on changing to landscape to put the width back to 100% and vise versa.
That is what Igot so far!

```
var selectBox = $("select").selectBoxIt().data("selectBoxIt");

window.onresize = function() {
    $("select").selectBoxIt().refresh();
}
```

Comment: try Selectize.js, select2 or chosen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following statement:

```
$('select').data('selectBox-selectBoxIt').refresh();
```

Comment: I used $("select:not([multiple])").each(function(index,value){$(value).data('selectBox-selectBoxIt').refresh()}); or it stopped at the first one as data only returns a single item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to change the CSS width of the select body, then you should use CSS3 media queries.

Comment: To rerender the select field i needed to call refresh() for using the whole select field as a tap area on mobile devices! $('#test').data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").refresh();